# Getting Javascript code to execute

Tags: javascript

So I'm following the tutorial from [This Site](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-jquery-david-sawyer-mcfarland-2nd/chapter-3/tutorial-a-simple-quiz) to learn some basic Javascript. The problem is, I don't have the book or the original source file.

Within my head I've got script with a function and a loop written, and then later in the  the script displays how many questions you got right. What I want to do is execute my loop down there too so it cycles through my questions.

Here is the script in the header:

```
<script>

var score = 0;

var questions = [
['what is 2+2?', 4],
['What is 2x3?', 6],
['What is 4+3?', 7]
];


function ask(question) {
var ans = prompt(question[0],'');
if (ans == question[1]){
    alert('You got it!');
    score++
} else {
    alert('Nope, not right. The answer is ' + question[1]);
}
}

for (var x=0; x<questions.length; x++) {
ask(questions[i]);
}



</script>
```

How do I get this to execute within the script tag of the body? I want the loop to cycle through my questions.

Comment: Your iteration variable is `x`, not `i`. Check the loop body.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your for loop is using `x` but you're trying to `ask` with `[i]`.

Edit: Since other observers are unclear, *this is the only thing preventing the code from running*, so it **is** the actual answer.

Comment: But the code should work fine as-is, once the error is fixed.

Comment: Wow, what a horribly silly mistake. I suppose I should have just stuck with i like the tutorial, but I typically use x.

Comment: A quick follow up, none of my HTML body shows until after the quiz is done. any way around that or is that how it will be with this format? edit: putting the loop into the body script seems to make that better

Comment: That's because your code doesn't have anything that would delay its execution; it will be run the instant the browser reads it. You can either move the script tag to the end of the page, or wrap the code in a function and register it to the window.onload event (or something like $(document).ready() in jQuery)

Comment: Sorry everyone is giving you trouble, that is exactly what my problem was. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue is that you are using `x` in your for loop while referring to `i` in your function call.

Fixed code:

```
var score = 0;

var questions = [
    ['what is 2+2?', 4],
    ['What is 2x3?', 6],
    ['What is 4+3?', 7]
];


function ask(question) {
    var ans = prompt(question[0], '');
    if (ans == question[1]) {
        alert('You got it!');
        score++
    } else {
        alert('Nope, not right. The answer is ' + question[1]);
    }
}

for (var x = 0; x < questions.length; x++) {
    ask(questions[x]);
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UWPt3/)